# why select count(*) not using index in database while using index in another database?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Both table using innodb engine

#### Prod environment: select count(*) not using index

[image]

version: 5.7.14-google-log

#### Dev environment: select count(*) using index

[image]

version: 5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

can somebody explain this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, neither `EXPLAIN` is telling the whole story.

In InnoDB, `SELECT COUNT(*)` without a `WHERE` must do an index scan.  The Optimizer will pick the 'smallest' index, which in your case is the `PRIMARY KEY`.

"Using index" agrees with the above statement.  But it is misleading until you realize the table is composed of the data with the PK clustered in it.

"Select tables optimized away" usually means that `EXPLAIN` performed a subquery rather than simply telling you what it was going to do.  (This can be slow for `EXPLAIN` if the subquery takes a long time.)

I assume there are no `VIEWs` involved here?

Note also that Google may have made some changes.  I suspect Ubuntu took 5.7.18 virtually as is.

Another issue...  In newer versions (I don't know when), MySQL stopped letting `EXPLAIN` "optimize away".